# How can I assert that a pdf file was returned in python?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-unittest

I am working on asserting that a pdf is returned from my request.

Here is what my test looks like so far.

```
@mock.patch('path.to.class._get_file', return_value=MockResponse(status.HTTP_200_OK, 'application/pdf'))
def test_get_should_successfully_return_the_requested_pdf(self, get_file_mock):
    response = self.client.get(f'/api/v1/path/to/file/abc123.pdf, content_type='application/vnd.api+json')

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)    # works great
    self.assertEqual(response['Content-Type'], 'application/pdf') # works great
    self.assertEqual(response, <abc123.pdf>) # not so great
```

If I do a `print` to see whats in the response:

```
print(response)

<HttpResponse status_code=200, "application/pdf"
```

I am pretty sure I am not setting up the `@patch` correctly. Specifically, this:

```
status.HTTP_200_OK, 'application/pdf'
```

I've seen a lot of posts about reading or opening files, but I just need to make sure it was in fact a pdf (file) that was returned.

How can I set my mock up so that I can assert a pdf (file) was returned?

Comment: response.content ?

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to share what I came up with after working with @godd0t suggestion which was super helpful. Your millage may vary depending on your `@patch` needs.

```
@mock.patch('path.to.class._get_file', return_value=MockResponse(status.HTTP_200_OK, b'MockPDF'))
def test_get_should_successfully_return_the_requested_pdf(self, get_file_mock):
    response = self.client.get(f'/api/v1/path/to/file/abc123.pdf, content_type='application/vnd.api+json')

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    self.assertEqual(response['Content-Type'], 'application/pdf')
    self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), str(get_file_mock.return_value))
```